# Java assertEquals causing failure in JUnit Testing

Tags: java, junit, hashcode, jdbctemplate, netbeans-8

I am working on a java jdbcTemplate project in Netbeans and I am having trouble figuring out what is wrong with my equals and hashcode methods overriding the assertEquals test for my Dao. I was instucted that I need to do a "deep comparison" on the object, but from what I can see, my code is already doing that. Below are my different classes involving this issue

**Here is my Organization.class:**

```
public class Organization {

    private int orgId;
    private String orgName;
    private String orgDescription;
    private String orgEmail;
    private String orgPhone;
    private Location orgLocation;

    
    
    
    public int getOrgId() {
        return orgId;
    }

    public void setOrgId(int orgId) {
        this.orgId = orgId;
    }

    public String getOrgName() {
        return orgName;
    }

    public void setOrgName(String orgName) {
        this.orgName = orgName;
    }

    public String getOrgDescription() {
        return orgDescription;
    }

    public void setOrgDescription(String orgDescription) {
        this.orgDescription = orgDescription;
    }

    public String getOrgEmail() {
        return orgEmail;
    }

    public void setOrgEmail(String orgEmail) {
        this.orgEmail = orgEmail;
    }

    public String getOrgPhone() {
        return orgPhone;
    }

    public void setOrgPhone(String orgPhone) {
        this.orgPhone = orgPhone;
    }

    public Location getOrgLocation() {
        return orgLocation;
    }

    public void setOrgLocation(Location orgLocation) {
        this.orgLocation = orgLocation;
    }

    
    
    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
        int hash = 7;
        hash = 67 * hash + this.orgId;
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgName);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgDescription);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgEmail);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgPhone);
        hash = 67 * hash + Objects.hashCode(this.orgLocation);
        return hash;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj) {
            return true;
        }
        if (obj == null) {
            return false;
        }
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
            return false;
        }
        final Organization other = (Organization) obj;
        if (this.orgId != other.orgId) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgName, other.orgName)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgDescription, other.orgDescription)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgEmail, other.orgEmail)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgPhone, other.orgPhone)) {
            return false;
        }
        if (!Objects.equals(this.orgLocation, other.orgLocation)) {
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
    
}
```

**Here is my Organization Dao Implementation:**

```
public class OrgDaoDBImpl implements OrgDao{
    
    private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

    public void setJdbcTemplate(JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate) {
        this.jdbcTemplate = jdbcTemplate;
    }

    
    //ORGANIZATIONS - PREPARED STATEMENTS
    
    private static final String SQL_INSERT_ORGANIZATION
            = "insert into `organization` (org_name, org_description, org_email, "
            + "org_phone, location_id) "
            + "values (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)";

    private static final String SQL_DELETE_ORGANIZATION
            = "delete from `organization` where org_id = ?";

    private static final String SQL_UPDATE_ORGANIZATION
            = "update `organization` set org_name = ?, org_description = ?, org_email = ?, "
            + "org_phone = ?, location_id = ? "
            + "where org_id =  ?";

    private static final String SQL_SELECT_ORGANIZATION
            = "select * from `organization` where org_id = ?";

    private static final String SQL_SELECT_ALL_ORGANIZATIONS
            = "select * from `organization`";
    

    
    private static final String SQL_SELECT_LOCATION_BY_ORG_ID
            = "select l.location_id, l.loc_name, l.loc_street_address, "
            + "l.loc_city, l.loc_state, l.loc_zip_code, l.loc_lat, l.loc_long " 
            + "from location l "
            + "join organization o on l.location_id = o.location_id  " 
            + "where o.org_id = ?";
 
    @Override
    @Transactional(propagation = Propagation.REQUIRED, readOnly = false)
    public void addOrganization(Organization organization) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_INSERT_ORGANIZATION,
            organization.getOrgName(),
            organization.getOrgDescription(),
            organization.getOrgPhone(),
            organization.getOrgEmail(),
            organization.getOrgLocation().getLocationId());
            organization.setOrgId(
                    jdbcTemplate.queryForObject("select LAST_INSERT_ID()", Integer.class));
            
    }

    @Override
    public void deleteOrganization(int organizationId) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_DELETE_ORGANIZATION, organizationId);
    }

    @Override
    public void updateOrganization(Organization organization) {
        jdbcTemplate.update(SQL_UPDATE_ORGANIZATION,
            organization.getOrgName(),
            organization.getOrgDescription(),
            organization.getOrgPhone(),
            organization.getOrgEmail(),
            organization.getOrgLocation().getLocationId());
    }

    @Override
    public Organization getOrganizationById(int id) {
        try {
            Organization org = jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_SELECT_ORGANIZATION,
                new OrgMapper(),
                id);
            org.setOrgLocation(findLocationForOrganization(org));
            return org;
        } catch (EmptyResultDataAccessException ex) {
            return null; 
            }
    }

    @Override
    public List<Organization> getAllOrganizations() {
        return jdbcTemplate.query(SQL_SELECT_ALL_ORGANIZATIONS, new OrgMapper());
    }

    @Override
    public List<Organization> getAllOrgsBySupeId(int supeId) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet."); //To change body of generated methods, choose Tools | Templates.
    }
    
    
    /////////////////////
    //*HELPER METHODS*//
    //***************//   
    
    //FIND Location associated with an organization
    private Location findLocationForOrganization(Organization org) {
        return jdbcTemplate.queryForObject(SQL_SELECT_LOCATION_BY_ORG_ID,
                                            new LocationMapper(), 
                                            org.getOrgId());
    }

    
    //ASSOCIATE the location with the org entry
    private List<Organization>associateLocationWithOrg(List<Organization> orgList) {
        // set the complete list of author ids for each book
        for (Organization currentOrg : orgList) {
            // add the Location to current Org
            currentOrg.setOrgLocation(findLocationForOrganization(currentOrg)); }
        return orgList; 
    }
    
    
    /////////////
    //*MAPPERS*/
    //*******//
    
    private static final class OrgMapper implements RowMapper<Organization> {
        
        @Override
        public Organization mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            Organization org = new Organization();
            org.setOrgId(rs.getInt("org_id"));
            org.setOrgName(rs.getString("org_name"));
            org.setOrgDescription(rs.getString("org_description"));
            org.setOrgPhone(rs.getString("org_phone"));
            org.setOrgEmail(rs.getString("org_email"));
            
              
            
            return org;
        
        }    
    }
    
    private static class LocationMapper implements RowMapper<Location>{
        
        @Override
        public Location mapRow(ResultSet rs, int i) throws SQLException {
            Location loc = new Location();
            loc.setLocationId(rs.getInt("location_id"));
            loc.setLocName(rs.getString("loc_name"));
            loc.setLocStreetAddress(rs.getString("loc_street_address"));
            loc.setLocCity(rs.getString("loc_city"));
            loc.setLocState(rs.getString("loc_state"));
            loc.setLocZipCode(rs.getString("loc_zip_code"));
            loc.setLocLat(rs.getString("loc_lat"));
            loc.setLocLong(rs.getString("loc_long"));

            
            return loc;
        }
    }
}
```

My Organization.class uses the Location object to input additional location information. So below, I first have to add a location before attempting to add an organization. At current, the test for adding a location is successful.

```
public class SuperSighting_DaoTests {
    
    LocationDao ldao;
    OrgDao odao;
    PowerDao pdao;
    SightingDao sidao;
    SupeDao sudao;
    
    public SuperSighting_DaoTests() {
    }
    
    @BeforeClass
    public static void setUpClass() {
    }
    
    @AfterClass
    public static void tearDownClass() {
    }
    
    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        ApplicationContext ctx
        = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("test-applicationContext.xml");
            
            ldao = ctx.getBean("LocationDao", LocationDao.class);
            odao = ctx.getBean("OrgDao", OrgDao.class);
            pdao = ctx.getBean("PowerDao", PowerDao.class);
            sidao = ctx.getBean("SightingDao", SightingDao.class);
            sudao = ctx.getBean("SupeDao", SupeDao.class);
            
            // delete all supes
            List<Supe> supes = sudao.getAllSupes(); for (Supe currentSupe : supes) {
            sudao.deleteSupe(currentSupe.getSupeId()); 
            }
            // delete all powers
            List<Power> powers = pdao.getAllPowers(); for (Power currentPower : powers) {
            pdao.deletePower(currentPower.getPowerId()); 
            }
            //delete all organizations
            List<Organization> orgs = odao.getAllOrganizations(); for (Organization currentOrg : orgs) {
            odao.deleteOrganization(currentOrg.getOrgId()); 
            }
            // delete all locations
            List<Location> locations = ldao.getAllLocations(); for (Location currentLocation : locations) {
            ldao.deleteLocation(currentLocation.getLocationId()); 
            }
            // delete all sightings
            List<Sighting> sightings = sidao.getAllSightings(); for (Sighting currentSighting : sightings) {
            sidao.deleteSighting(currentSighting.getSightingId()); 
            }
    }
    @Test
    public void testAddGetOrganization() {
        
        Location loc = new Location();
        loc.setLocName("Legion of Doom");
        loc.setLocStreetAddress("127 Taco St.");
        loc.setLocCity("Smalltown");
        loc.setLocState("MA");
        loc.setLocZipCode("19698");
        loc.setLocLat("39.16567925978815");
        loc.setLocLong("-75.59452746539126");
        
        ldao.addLocation(loc);
    
        Organization org = new Organization();
        org.setOrgName("Legion of Doom");
        org.setOrgDescription("evil organization");
        org.setOrgPhone("333-444-5678");
        org.setOrgEmail("lod@evil.org");
        org.setOrgLocation(loc);
        
        odao.addOrganization(org);

 
        
        Organization fromDao = odao.getOrganizationById(org.getOrgId());
        fromDao.toString();

        assertEquals(fromDao, org);
    
    }
```

When the test completes, I can see that the compared items are exactly the same, but the test fails and gives me this error:

> Tests run: 8, Failures: 1, Errors: 0, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 2.931
> sec <<< FAILURE!
> testAddGetOrganization(com.sg.supersightingsv2.dao.SuperSighting_DaoTests)
> Time elapsed: 0.177 sec  <<< FAILURE! java.lang.AssertionError:
> expected:com.sg.supersightingsv2.model.Organization@ad172ff9 but
> was:com.sg.supersightingsv2.model.Organization@e8c8a831     at
> org.junit.Assert.fail(Assert.java:88)

Here is the image showing the field values for both objects ('org' and 'fromDao') being compared:[two object being compared](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EUKkL.png)

I am just really unsure where to go from here because my end goal relies on the test passing. I have gone through the code many many times, and I am at a lost for what to do other that rewriting the whole program. Any suggestions are appreciated as I am still new to this! Thank you!

Comment: Use a debugger to set a breakpoint at the assert and check if the two objects are really the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wanted to delete this question but I can't. -thanks for the quick reponses!

I somehow fixed this issue... It actually turned out that my phone and email entires were getting switched on retrieval -you can see this in the screenshot...its easy to miss after hours of staring.

I went through all my code and switched the order to match the database and my tests are al green now.

Thanks again!

Comment: I see the problem: the definitionof the prepared statements (like `SQL_INSERT_ORGANIZATION` and `SQL_UPDATE_ORGANIZATION`) is at the beginning of your DAO class and the usage is dozens of lines later, so it is easy to miss that the prepared statements expect the "org_email" before the "org_phone", but you set the parameters in the reverse order (`organization.getOrgPhone(), organization.getOrgEmail(),`). That's one of the reasons why I either inline those constants or define them just above the method(s) that uses them...

Comment: Yes, I did later notice that those 2 items were being switched when the object was retrieved.

Answer (score 2):

deleted: totally wrong - should have checked screenshots with more care